# What are the perks and privileges enjoyed by the non-EU/UK/CA/AU/NATO allies of US?

Tags: united-states, international-relations

I am from one of those countries that claims to be a US ally. I don't know whether there is or should be any military connotation linked to that. If there is, I wonder if there are any benefits of such a partnership. In the state of war, does the US come to the rescue? Or in times of economic crisis, does the US help in stabilizing the economy? Please elaborate.

Comment: I imagine the "perks" would vary from country to country. Would you be able to clarify *which* country exactly it is that you're from?

Comment: Your profile says you're from Norway, but the title specifies "non-NATO allies of [the] US" and Norway is a NATO member, so I'm unsure whether you're referring to a different country or simply unaware that Norway doesn't meet the criteria specified in the title.

Comment: For the Republic of China (Taiwan) this question is explicitly unanswerable, as the US is deliberately secret about what military aid it would give in what circumstances.

Comment: hosting bases or smaller forces. opportunity to buy the newest NATO weapons. improvement in negotiating position vs neighbors which are small neutral countries. government more likely to receive NATO support vs its domestic opposition, in exchange for maintaining the alliance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_non-NATO_ally

Comment: You can buy their weapons. They are disgustingly over-priced, but sometimes really good quality. Beside that, having well armed with USA weapons has also an extra deterrent effect. You might also get economical or duty allowances, so you can sell things to the USA cheaply and buy from them cheaply. Most importantly, weapons. For example, Turkey can buy both USA weapons and Russian oil, it was surely not easy to reach politically!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the treaty, the relations, and the geopolitical situation.

First, a look at the military situation.

At one end of the spectrum we have Japan. The US is very direct in protecting Japan. The treaty, a descendant of the one ending WWII, is clear, and US positioning is unequivocal. Attack Japan, and you basically attack the US.

At the other end of the spectrum is Ukraine. The governing treaty has ironclad assurances that the US and Russia will respect Ukraine's 1991 borders. However, it does not require either provide military engagement when they were invaded. As we can see, the US didn't provide direct military assistance when Russians invaded in 2014 or 2022.

Most of the rest are somewhere in between, but it varies. US stance towards defending Taiwan in case of attack is deliberately unspecific. On the other hand, the Philippines can be a lot more sure in their protection should they be attacked.

From a military perspective, the benefits of defensive treaties depends greatly on a lot of different factors.

In terms of economic assistance, defense treaties may factor in, but aren't the only factor. A great deal of US economic aid goes to nations not formally allied with the US.

A secondary effect of the defense pact discussion, though, is the US (and a lot of the West) will often push for or require certain rule of law or democratic reforms as part of this. Even NATO itself requires such things for membership. While these are not economic aid, the Western world generally sees a strong correlation, and other reason to believe in causation, between such things and a healthy economy that benefits the whole population, not just the elites.

Finally, defense pacts with Western nations tend to bring stability and sureity that feeds economic progress. While wars are less common than previous generations, they are still a concern, and risk to stability or surety are risks to investment and growth.

Comment: Ukraine is not officially [even] a MNNA. There's is a US law that (theoretically) forces the administration to treat Taiwan as a MNNA without such a desgination https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/86440/why-was-saudi-arabia-not-granted-the-status-of-major-non-nato-ally-of-the-us As with all defense matters, I suspect a lot would depend on the administration (in place at a given time).

Comment: As for pressing for democratic reforms, the US doesn't seem too interested in pressing e.g. MNNA Egypt with that.

Comment: The question doesn't bring up MNNA or differentiate what level of allies are being discussed. Hence the answer focusing on the "it depends" side of things. An answer discussing MNNA vs other forms of allies might make an even better answer, but I'm not up to writing it.